# CORS Request XMLHttpRequest cannot load Invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

My Web Application(ASP.NET MVC5) hosted in Server A and Rest Service(WebAPI) is hosted in Server B. When the application access the WebAPI through IE11 , it works fine but in chrome, i got the error message as **no access-control-allow-origin header is present**

After Googling, i added this in the Web.config of WebAPI

```
<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

And the below one in the client side call

```
var config = {
            headers: {

                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                'X-Requested-With': 'XmlHttpRequest'
            }
        };

        $http.get(url, config).success(function (data) {
            var filteredData = data;
})
```

Now i m getting authorization error
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load (URL) Invalid HTTP status code 401**

Also i have one more query, to overcome CORS error, do we need to add information only in client side or in server side or both required?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to make any specific CORS configurations in your client-side request. The browser (Chrome, in your case) should send the proper headers.

EDIT: if you are support credentials on the server side (see note below), then you need to include the following in your ajax requests:

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

See [`xhrFields` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

For the server side, I would recommend installing the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors) NuGet package, and then follow [these configuration instructions](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).  In particular, see [this section](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope) which explains how you can enable CORS per action, per controller, or globally for all Web API controllers in your application.

For example:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetItem(int id) { ... }
```

If you are going to use the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header with a value of `true` then the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header cannot be `*`. It has to be set to one or more specific domains.

Comment: Hi David, I tried it but as i pointed out, no access-control-allow-origin header is present but i m getting Unauthorized error code 401

Comment: You originally mentioned that you were getting the error "no access-control-allow-origin header is present" from Chrome. Are you still seeing that error now? Or are you only getting a 401 response?  If you are only getting a 401 response, make sure you don't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `'*'` if you also have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` set to `true`. See the comment in my answer above.

Comment: i would like to connect with you in office to explain more on the issue. I dont know where i missing but still its not working properly